# How do i create sleep function in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google script code with loops defined in its, but i need a function that will delay the loop execution by 45 secs.

```js
function SendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startrow = 2;
  // First row of data to process
  var numrows = 100;
  // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startrow, 1, numrows, 100)
  //Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for(i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    //First COlumn
    var message = row[1];
    // Second Column
    var subject = row[2];
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

As of now i was thinking if i could use sleep function, since i am newbie for coding i don't have any idea how to go about it?

Any help here.

Comment: Take a look at the [`sleep(milliseconds)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities?hl=en#sleep(Integer)) function, maybe it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Utilities class, most specifically the sleep() method; Utilities.sleep(ms);
It makes your script to «sleep» for a defined amount of milliseconds. Keep in mind that the maximum value is 300000 (5 minutes) since the script itself can only run for 6 minutes, given the limitation of the Google Apps Script environment.
Here's the link to the documentation; [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep%28Integer%29)